# "projektiert" vs. "projeziert"

Tags: meaning, latin

Ich kenne nur "projeziert", das Partizip "projektiert" ist mir neu. Gefunden in

```
"Das projektierte Großsyrien umfasste folgende heutige Staatsgebiete: [...]."
```

aus [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCrgerkrieg_in_Syrien#Hintergrund). Handelt es sich um eine mögliche Beugung eines Latinismus, oder um ein eigenes Partizip zu einem Verb "*projektieren", oder ist es ein Fehler?

Comment: [Projektieren im Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/projektieren) und [projezieren oder projizieren?](http://www.lektor.at/beliebte-rechtschreibfehler/l-bis-s/projezieren-oder-projizieren/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Partizipien „projiziert“ und „projektiert“ kommen von unterschiedlichen Verben. Ersteres von „projizieren“, letzteres von „projektieren“. Die Bedeutung von „projektieren“ ist „planen, entwerfen“.

An dieser Stelle ist „projektiert“ also korrekt.

Beide Verben haben ihre Herkunft im lat. „proicere“ (= „hinwerfen“), letzteres machte aber einen Umweg über das Partizip Perfekt Passiv „proiectum“ (= „das Hingeworfene“), siehe auch „Projekt“.

Quellen:
[Wiktionary: projizieren](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/projizieren)
[Wiktionary: projektieren](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/projektieren)
[Wiktionary: Projekt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Projekt)

Comment: Warum sagt man dann: projektive Geometrie und nicht projizierende Geometrie?